# Pass regex options to PowerShell [regex] type

Tags: regex, powershell, case-insensitive

I capture two groups matched using the regexp code below:

```
[regex]$regex = "^([0-9]{1,20})(b|kb|mb|gb|tb)$"

$matches = $regex.match($minSize)

$size=[int64]$matches.Groups[1].Value
$unit=$matches.Groups[2].Value
```

My problem is I want to make it case-insensitive, and I do not want to use regex modifiers.

I know you can pass regex options in .NET, but I cannot figure out how to do the same with PowerShell.

Comment: As a small side note, the pattern might be shortened using an optional character class instead of the alternation `^([0-9]{1,20})([kmgt]?b)$`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using -match instead. E.g.,

```
$minSize = "20Gb"
$regex = "^([0-9]{1,20})(b|kb|mb|gb|tb)$"
$minSize -match $regex #Automatic $Matches variable created
$size=[int64]$Matches[1]
$unit=$Matches[2]
```

Answer (score 17):

There are overloads of the static [`[Regex]::Match()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match) method that allow to provide the desired `[RegexOptions]` programmatically:

```bsh
# You can combine several options by doing a bitwise or:
$options = [Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase -bor [Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::CultureInvariant
# or by letting casting do the magic:
$options = [Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]'IgnoreCase, CultureInvariant'

$match = [regex]::Match($input, $regex, $options)
```

Comment: Great answer!  The accepted answer handles the OPs specific problem for case insensitivity, but this handles the general case to pass in any flags/options to the regex.

Answer (score 8):

Use PowerShell's -match operator instead. By default it is case-insensitive:

```
$minSize -match '^([0-9]{1,20})(b|kb|mb|gb|tb)$'
```

For case-sensitive matches, use -cmatch.

Comment: thanks but accepted the answer from aquinas as he provided the complete example for me

Answer (score 3):

You can also include [mode modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) like `(?i)` in your regex, like so (cmatch forces case sensitive match):

```
PS H:\> 'THISISSOMETHING' -cmatch 'something'
False
PS H:\> 'THISISSOMETHING' -cmatch '(?i)something'
True
```

Comment: That may be valid, in general, but the OP said he did not want to do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

After using `[regex]` type accelerator, Options property is ReadOnly and can't be changed. But you can call a constructor with RegexOptions parameter:

```
$regex = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::new('^([0-9]{1,20})(b|kb|mb|gb|tb)$','IgnoreCase')
```

To pass multiple options use bitwise or operator on underlying values:

```
$regex = [regex]::new('^([0-9]{1,20})(b|kb|mb|gb|tb)$',[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline.value__ -bor [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase.value__)
```

But simple addition seems to work, too:

```
[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline + System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase
```

It would even work when supplied numeric flag (35 = IgnoreCase=1 + MultiLine=2 + IgnorePatternWhitespace=32), altough relying on enum values directly is usually not a best practice:

```
$regex = [regex]::new('^([0-9]{1,20})(b|kb|mb|gb|tb)$',36)
$regex.Options
```

Comment: Simple addition works as the options are bit flags and don't overlap. Also, the first example shows that Powershell allows a string for a function parameter that expects an enumeration (value). Powershell substitutes the value for the enumeration member which has a name that is a unique (possibly partial) match for the string value. But Powershell also allows multiple member values to be bitwise ORed by including all the (full not partial) names in a comma separated list (see argonym answer). 2nd example could be `$regex = [regex]::new('^([0-9]{1,20})(b|kb|mb|gb|tb)$','ignorecase,multiline')`