# How to get the captured groups from Select-String?

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string, select-object

I'm trying to extract text from a set of files on Windows using the Powershell (version 4):

```
PS > Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern <mypattern-with(capture)> -Path file.jsp | Format-Table
```

So far, so good. That gives a nice set of `MatchInfo` objects:

```
IgnoreCase                    LineNumber Line                          Filename                      Pattern                       Matches
----------                    ---------- ----                          --------                      -------                       -------
    True                            30   ...                           file.jsp                      ...                           {...}
```

Next, I see that the captures are in the matches member, so I take them out:

```
PS > Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern <mypattern-with(capture)> -Path file.jsp | ForEach-Object -MemberName Matches | Format-Table
```

Which gives:

```
Groups        Success Captures                 Index     Length Value
------        ------- --------                 -----     ------ -----
{...}         True    {...}                    49        47     ...
```

or as list with `| Format-List`:

```
Groups   : {matched text, captured group}
Success  : True
Captures : {matched text}
Index    : 39
Length   : 33
Value    : matched text
```

Here's where I stop, I have no idea how to go further and obtain a list of *captured group* elements.

I've tried adding another `| ForEach-Object -MemberName Groups`, but it seems to return the same as the above.

The closest I get is with `| Select-Object -Property Groups`, which indeed gives me what I'd expect (a list of sets):

```
Groups
------
{matched text, captured group}
{matched text, captured group}
...
```

But then I'm unable to extract the *captured group* from each of them, I tried with `| Select-Object -Index 1` I get only one of those sets.

---

### Update: a possible solution

It seems that by adding `| ForEach-Object { $_.Groups.Groups[1].Value }` I got what I was looking for, but I don't understand why - so I can't be sure I would be able to get the right result when extending this method to whole sets of files.

Why is it working?

As a side note, this `| ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }` (i.e. without the second `.Groups`) gives the same result.

I'd like to add that, upon further attempts, it seems the command can be shortened by removing the piped `| Select-Object -Property Groups`.

Comment: Every match have implicit group `0`, which is a match itself. So, in your case `Groups` collection have two elements: match itself and first capturing group. If you want only capturing group, then you have to specify it by `Groups[1]`.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Have a look at the following

```
$a = "http://192.168.3.114:8080/compierews/" | Select-String -Pattern '^http://(.*):8080/(.*)/$'
```

`$a` is now a `MatchInfo` (`$a.gettype()`) it contain a `Matches` property.

```
PS ps:\> $a.Matches
Groups   : {http://192.168.3.114:8080/compierews/, 192.168.3.114, compierews}
Success  : True
Captures : {http://192.168.3.114:8080/compierews/}
Index    : 0
Length   : 37
Value    : http://192.168.3.114:8080/compierews/
```

in the groups member you'll find what you are looking for so you can write :

```
"http://192.168.3.114:8080/compierews/" | Select-String -Pattern '^http://(.*):8080/(.*)/$'  | % {"IP is $($_.matches.groups[1]) and path is $($_.matches.groups[2])"}

IP is 192.168.3.114 and path is compierews
```

Comment: Without the leading spaces the asterisk isn't being displayed in the capture groups in the second line of the answer (where you assign to `$a`). I tried editing but got an error because my edit is less than six characters. IOW, the capture groups appear as `(.)` instead of `(.*)` as you intended.

Comment: What is the % {""} syntax in the last statement?

Comment: `%` is an Alias for `ForEach-Object`. then you can handle each object with `$_`.

Comment: I had to use `$_.matches.groups[1].value` outside of a string literal.

Comment: Any idea why my console prints `Groups   : {0, 1, 2}` rather than `Groups   : {http://192.168.3.114:8080/compierews/, 192.168.3.114, compierews}` as in your output?
Did they change how powershell formats that output?

Comment: Sorry , I don't know, but it's just presention.

Answer (score 23):

According to the powershell docs on [Regular Expressions > Groups, Captures, and Substitutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7#groups-captures-and-substitutions):

When using the `-match` operator, powershell will create an [*automatic variable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#matches) named **`$Matches`**

```cs
PS> "The last logged on user was CONTOSO\jsmith" -match "(.+was )(.+)"
```

The value returned from this expression is just `true`|`false`, but PS will add the `$Matches` *hashtable*

So if you output `$Matches`, you'll get all capture groups:

```
PS> $Matches

Name     Value
----     -----
2        CONTOSO\jsmith
1        The last logged on user was
0        The last logged on user was CONTOSO\jsmith
```

And you can access each capture group individually with dot notation like this:

```
PS> "The last logged on user was CONTOSO\jsmith" -match "(.+was )(.+)"
PS> $Matches.2
CONTOSO\jsmith
```

**Additional Resources**:

- To Get Multiple Matches, see [How to capture multiple regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24190283/1366033)
- To Pass Options/Flags, see [Pass regex options to PowerShell `[regex]` type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336328/1366033)

Comment: I seem to have to use indexer for it in PS7? Also, if you need a oneliner to print something out, you can do `"my text to match" -match "t(ext)"|Out-Null;$Matches[1]`

Comment: And, if you're doing it on string arrays by accident, then `-match` behaves differently, and you could consider joining your array to a string `($myVar -join '``n') -match ...` (with only one backtick [`], but couldn't get the formatting to work)

Answer (score 9):

Late answer, but to loop multiple matches and groups I use:

```
$pattern = "Login:\s*([^\s]+)\s*Password:\s*([^\s]+)\s*"
$matches = [regex]::Matches($input_string, $pattern)

foreach ($match in $matches)
{
    Write-Host  $match.Groups[1].Value
    Write-Host  $match.Groups[2].Value
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This worked for my situation.

Using the file: `__test.txt__`

```
// autogenerated by script
char VERSION[21] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST";
char NUMBER[16] = "123456789012345";
```

Get the NUMBER and VERSION from the file.

```
PS C:\> Select-String -Path test.txt -Pattern 'VERSION\[\d+\]\s=\s\"(.*)\"' | %{$_.Matches.Groups[1].value}

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST

PS C:\> Select-String -Path test.txt -Pattern 'NUMBER\[\d+\]\s=\s\"(.*)\"' | %{$_.Matches.Groups[1].value}

123456789012345
```

Answer (score -1):

This script will grab a regex's specified capture group from a file's content and output its matches to console.

---

`$file` is the file you want to load
`$cg` is capture group you want to grab
`$regex` is the regular expression pattern

---

---

Example file and its content to load:

#### C:\some\file.txt

`This is the especially special text in the file.`

---

---

Example Use: `.\get_regex_capture.ps1 -file "C:\some\file.txt" -cg 1 -regex '\b(special\W\w+)'`

Output: `special text`

---

#### get_regex_capture.ps1

```
Param(
    $file=$file,
    [int]$cg=[int]$cg,
    $regex=$regex
)
[int]$capture_group = $cg
$file_content = [string]::Join("`r`n", (Get-Content -Raw "$file"));
Select-String -InputObject $file_content -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches.Captures } | % { echo $_.Groups[$capture_group].Value }
```