# Extracting String Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

Im trying to extract the loankey from the following text in powershell:

```
Test\errorlog.txt:4::293:StepName:WARNING StepTime:9/9/2016 9:01:06 AM StepMessage:ERROR(KEY1:7798850,LOANKEY:11111)::POST PAYMENT StepNotes:[[WARNING]]
Test\errorlog.txt:8::299:StepName:WARNING StepTime:9/9/2016 9:01:11 AM StepMessage:ERROR(KEY1:7798870,LOANKEY:54321)::POST PAYMENT StepNotes:[[WARNING]]
Test\errorlog.txt:12::305:StepName:WARNING StepTime:9/9/2016 9:01:14 AM StepMessage:ERROR(KEY1:7798863,LOANKEY:12345)::POST PAYMENT StepNotes:[[WARNING]]
```

I have currently got the following to filter down the error log down to how you see it above:

```
cls

$path = 'C:\Test\errorlog.txt'

$script = select-string -pattern "LOANKEY:" $path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select-string -pattern "LOANKEY:(.*)\)" .\errorlog.txt | % {"$($_.matches.groups[1])"}
```

then you'll get what you want. 
reference here: [How to get the captured groups from Select-String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913878/how-to-get-the-captured-groups-from-select-string)

Comment: the Answer from @paweł-dyl is also great, just with "more" we can save the variable definition:

`more .\errorlog.txt | % { [Regex]::Match($_, "(?<=LOANKEY:)(\d+)").Value }`

Answer (score 1):

Having mentioned input you can use regex:

```
$txt = "Test\errorlog.txt:4::293:StepName:WARNING StepTime:9/9/2016 9:01:06 AM StepMessage:ERROR(KEY1:7798850,LOANKEY:11111)::POST PAYMENT StepNotes:[[WARNING]]",
"Test\errorlog.txt:8::299:StepName:WARNING StepTime:9/9/2016 9:01:11 AM StepMessage:ERROR(KEY1:7798870,LOANKEY:54321)::POST PAYMENT StepNotes:[[WARNING]]",
"Test\errorlog.txt:12::305:StepName:WARNING StepTime:9/9/2016 9:01:14 AM StepMessage:ERROR(KEY1:7798863,LOANKEY:12345)::POST PAYMENT StepNotes:[[WARNING]]"

$txt | % { [Regex]::Match($_, "(?<=LOANKEY:)(\d+)").Value }
```