# PowerShell regex capture differences

Tags: regex, powershell

The goal is to get only the leading digits before a SPACE character from a string. When I use `-replace` in PowerShell, leading alphabetic characters are included. Why is this different?

```
PS C:\src\t> 'aasdf123 456' -replace '([\d]+) .*', '$1'
aasdf123
```

This does not occur on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) which produces.

```
123
```

**Not a duplicate**

The question is not how to get the number. The question is why does `'aasdf'` match `\d`. The capture group specifies only `\d`.

Comment: You need to match, not replace.

Comment: 'aasdf123 456' -replace '^([a-zA-Z]+)([\d]+)\s(.*)$', '$2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is expected.

**The `-replace` operator *removes* all non-overlapping matches from the input string *keeping* all non-matched parts in the result.**

The `'aasdf123 456' -replace '([\d]+) .*', '$1'` will return `assdf123` because the `([\d]+) .*` (equal to `(\d+) .*`) matches and captures into Group 1 one or more digits, then matches a space and then the rest of the line, and then the whole match (here, `123 456`) is replaced with the contents of Group 1, `123`, thus, keeping `assdf123` as the result of the `-replace` operation.

Your statement that regex101 produces another result is wrong: [it produces the *same* result](https://regex101.com/r/TjL4UB/2/):

[image]

Even if you look at the *`MATCH INFORMATION`* pane, there are two values: the whole match, `123 456`, and the Group 1 value, `123`. So, there is no discrepancy at all.

To get just `123`, you may use the solution described in [How to get the captured groups from Select-String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913878/how-to-get-the-captured-groups-from-select-string)

Comment: I see that using -match works. I would like to mark this as the answer. But, I would like to know how `assdf` got into a group containing only `\d`.

Comment: @lit Please see *The `'aasdf123 456' -replace '([\d]+) .*', '$1'` will return `assdf123` because the `([\d]+) .*` (equal to `(\d+) .*`) matches and captures into Group 1 one or more digits, then matches a space and then the rest of the line, and then the whole match (here, `123 456`) is replaced with the contents of Group 1, `123`, thus, keeping `assdf123` as the result of the `-replace` operation.* `assdf` *NEVER* got into any group, it **was not matched**. It is clearly seen on the regex101 screenshot: that part of string is not highlighted.

Comment: And again: *The `-replace` operator removes all non-overlapping matches from the input string **keeping all non-matched parts in the result**.*

Comment: Ok. I am marking this as the answer. It looks like that since 'aasdf' was not matched, it was kept in the output result. I still have to think about this some more.