# Speeding Up Regular Expression Matching

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm searching with thousands of regular expressions and it seems to take a long time on that part. If you happen to know of a faster way to search each line for all of the regex's, I'm all ears.

I need to capture the value matched, the full line that matched, and the line number.

```
$file = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader ($CSVFile)  # Input Stream
    while (($text = $file.ReadLine()) -ne $null ){
        foreach ($RX in $SearchList){
            foreach ($match in ([regex]$RX).Matches($text)) {
                    write-host "Match found: " $match.value -ForegroundColor Red     
            }
        }
    }
$file.close();
```

Comment: Without looking at regex how one can tell you how to improve ?

Comment: Do you need to know if a particular regex matches multiple times in the file? Do you need to know which line matched? How big are the files?

Comment: The regex's do match, I'm just attempting to speed up the processing of the regex matching.

Comment: The fastest way will be to get rid of regexps.

Comment: @MrMr Why do you compile each RX again for every line? That's completely unnecessary. Regular expressions should be compiled once and then be reused often.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea... but I'm not sure how to do that yet. =)

Comment: @MrMr Assign your regex first to a variable name (I believe PowerShell will compile at that time) and use the variable name in your second foreach loop. Should remove the compile time out of every iteration.

Comment: I tried foreach ($match in ([regex]$global:SearchList).Matches($text)) {} but it doesn't seem to work. I get an error saying "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex""

Comment: is there a reason why you are running each regex individually? you can speed things up a very great deal by using a regex OR - the `|` symbol. then it becomes one test instead of "thousands of tests".

Answer (score 1):

Matching something against thousands of regular expressions in a loop will always perform poorly. Merge your individual regular expressions into one

```
$re = $SearchList -join '|'
```

and use it like this:

```
(Get-Content $CSVFile) -match $re
```

or like this (if the input file is too large to fit into memory):

```
Get-Content $CSVFile | Where-Object { $_ -match $re }
```

If you have too many individual regular expressions to fit into one large one you need to find a way to reduce their number or merge several of them into smaller, more general ones. For help with doing that you need to provide us with a representative sample of the expressions you want to match against.